# Neovim - Shortcut for native autocomplete Ctrl + n

Tags: lua, neovim

*Hello*, I want to add a shortcut in neovim to take advantage of its native autocomplete which is activated with `Ctrl + n`, when typing in insert mode I want to press tab and autocomplete. The following codes work for me, especially the lua code. But there's a problem:

When I use this shortcut I lose the tab function, I'm looking for a way to make this shortcut only work when there is a word before the cursor; otherwise the tab should work normally. I appreciate the help in advance.

**Lua**

```
map('i', '<Tab>', '<c-n>', {noremap = true})
```

**Vimscript**

```
imap <Tab> <c-o><c-n>
```

**Note:** This question addresses native nvim 'Ctrl + n' autocompletion and not autocomplete plugins. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not autocompletion, this is still manual completion. For autocompletion, no trigger key is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
inoremap <expr><Tab> CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" : "\<C-n>"

function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```

I took the CheckBackspace() function from [coc.nvim plugin's](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) example config.